# Macros that can lead to double periods at end of sentence

Tags: macros, punctuation

Suppose that a document makes a heavy use of one of the abbreviations *PhD*, *Ph.D.*, *DPhil* and *D.Phil.*, and for the sake of consistency the author decides to define a `\PhD` macro and use it whenever they need the abbreviation.  So, they pick up on of these definitions:

```
\def\PhD{PhD}%
\def\PhD{Ph.D.}%
\def\PhD{DPhil}%
\def\PhD{D.Phil.}%
```

Now, the problem is that a sentence like

*A "graduate student" is a student pursuing education past the bachelor's degree, such as a master's degree or a `\PhD`.*

could be typeset with two periods at the end depending on the definition of `\PhD`.  How can we avoid this problem without giving up the idea to use a `\PhD` macro?  (Assume that we can change the macro definitions.)

Comment: `\makeatletter\def\PhD{Ph.D\@ifnextchar.{}{.}}\makeatother`

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this was your intend by I try it:

```
\long\def\isnextchar#1#2#3{\def\tmpa{#2}\def\tmpb{#3}%
   \let\tmp=#1\futurelet\next\isnextcharA
}
\def\isnextcharA{\ifx\tmp\next\expandafter\tmpa\else\expandafter\tmpb\fi}

\def\PhD{\isnextchar.{PhD}{Ph.D.}}
\def\PhD{\isnextchar.{PhD}{Ph.D.}}

The \PhD\ inside the sentence is different than \PhD.
gives:
The Ph.D. inside the sentence is different than PhD.

\bye
```

Comment: this will work for "Ph.D.", but for "D.Phil.", unless `\frenchspacing` is used, the space after the the substitution in the middle of the sentence will be treated as a sentence-ending space.  (and for `\PhD`, the space after it will be just an "ordinary" space at the end of a sentence.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton After we will know more about OP's intend then we can tune details. At this moment, the usage of `\PhD\ ` or `\PhD.` (at the end of the sentence) works OK, because the `\ ` space is independent of the spacefactor. But I doubt that OP needs this. Maybe I didn't understand something...

Answer (score 4):

Periods are a strange beast, because the space factor must be set correctly (of course, if you use `\nonfrenchspacing`).

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\checkperiod{\futurelet\next\check@period}
\def\check@period{%
  \if\noexpand\next.%
    \spacefactor\sfcode`.
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \fi}
\long\def\@gobble#1{}
\def\@{\spacefactor\@m}
\catcode`@=12

\xspaceskip=4em % just to verify

\def\PhD{PhD\@}

A \PhD{} and another \PhD. End.

\def\PhD{Ph.D.\checkperiod}

A \PhD{} and another \PhD. End.

\def\PhD{DPhil}

A \PhD{} and another \PhD. End.

\def\PhD{D.Phil.\@\checkperiod}

A \PhD{} and another \PhD. End.

\bye
```

The setting of `\xspaceskip` is just to show that the space factor is computed correctly.

In the case of “no period in abbreviation”, the macro `\@` borrowed from LaTeX sets the space factor to 1000, so a period after `\PhD` with the first definition will be still considered sentence ending.

[image]

Comment: It should be possible to leave out the `{}` when calling the macro, right? So `A \PhD and another…`, instead of `\PhD{}`.

Comment: @jmc Not really. In LaTeX there's the `xspace` package, but it's complicated to port to Plain and not really useful. Instead of `{}` one can use “control space”.

Comment: — I see. Thanks! I didn't really register that `xspace`-like behaviour is not (easily) available in Plain-TeX.